# What to do about obsolete questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently started digging through some of the old unanswered YouTube questions, and I stumbled over several that don't really make sense anymore. Like [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/are-playlist-videos-supposed-to-autoplay-even-when-autoplay-is-disabled-for-the): The user is asking about the autoplay button in playlists, but there no longer is an autoplay button.

So far I've commented on those questions that they're obsolete, but due to SE's design it feels like this may be missed by users; I'd rather have a big yellow banner saying something among the lines of "ye who enter, abandon this thread! there is no answer, for the feature is no longer!"

Is just commenting the way to go, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a custom close reason under *Off-topic* that reads:

> Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

For the scenario you're describing, the appropriate thing to do is to close the question with that reason. Since you don't have enough reputation to vote to close, you should using the flagging system. There should be an option under there "should be closed" and the same information as above. (You may need to follow a couple of links.) Using that flag will put the question into the Close review queue, where people who do have enough reputation to vote to close can act on it.

That said, it's not *wrong* to comment on the question. It's a good idea to point out where a feature is no longer available, in case the question doesn't get closed or is useful for other reasons.

Comment: I hope that such closed questions stay in the system somewhere. You can never tell when a removed feature might be restored, and suddenly all the _off topic_ questions are _on topic_ once more. Sometimes the user base just won't let a beloved feature fade away.